# Magma for Central Extension

Tags: group-theory

How to use magma to find the the central extension of any group, for example how to use magma to find the central extension of the symmetric group S10.

Answer (score 1):

```
> G:=Sym(10);
> F:=FPGroup(G);
> E :=pCover(G,F,2);
```

will work, but the covering group $E$ is returned as a finite presentation. In this case it is possible to compute a faithful permutation representation of $E$, but you would not be able to do this with groups that were much larger than $S_{10}$.